# Multithreaded HTTP Request Queue System Approach

Tags: android, ios, multithreading, locking, httprequest

I've read alot of different recommendations on how to use locks - but the behavior of my current code in both IOS and Android does not behave correctly.

What I'm trying to do is build a queue system with a HTTP Request. If a Request fails, it should be the first request to be retried. Both send and add to queue is in the same method, so it shall not add a new object into the queue until the previous request has finished. If one fails and when the next request gets added it would send two requests (in the same package and clearing the queue).

Android:

```
// Java
synchronized(locker)
{
    Add object to a queue if there is a new object to be added
    If any objects in queue - send request with AsyncTask
}
```

IOS:

```
// Objective-C
@synchronized(locker)
{
    Add object to a queue if there is a new object to be added
    If any objects in queue - send request with NSURLSessionDataTask
}
```

...and on fail, do not remove the object from the queue.

In this case - I am guessing that the lock does get released and another thread could possibly be sending the next request right away and come first since the tasks are dispatched in another thread?

I've tried with normal locks with some success on Android and complete failure on iOS where the entire system freezed up. Since then I've read about locking a lock on IOS that it has to be unlocked by the same thread - would a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()... on the entire method work or would I have to dispatched it again when the completitionHandler finishes? Can I be certain that the completitionHandler is called on the same thread as the method creating it?

It's very important that each package are sent in the correct order. What is the best approach towards a multithreaded HTTP Request system like this?

Comment: Your question isn't making a lot of sense to me.  "Both send and add to queue is in the same method, so it shall not add a new object into the queue until the previous request has finished".  Wouldn't this make it not a queue?  If you can't add a new request until the last one is sent?  Also, why would you implement your own locking rather than using a ConcurrentLinkedQueue or the like?  Nor do I understand what problem you're having, you aren't explaining it well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't spawn new threads by `AsyncTask` or `NSURLSessionDataTask`. If you need the threads to serialize, i.e. at most one of them may run at the same time, and the next one has to wait for the first one to finish completely, there's absolutely no reason to run multiple threads.

You're going to want one (1) thread for all requests, and maybe send data to it using a queue. Otherwise, the UI might freeze while sending http requests.